# Übersetzung von „Neo-Victorian“

Tags: translation

Hat dieses Genre im Deutschen einen Eigennamen, oder wurde es bis jetzt einfach nicht übersetzt?

(Bei einer Google-Suche find ich nur automatische Übersetzungen von z.B. Etsy.)

Comment: Und was sagt diese automatische Übersetzung? Neovictorianisch?

Comment: @userunknown Jupp.

Comment: Warum eigenltich ein `k`? Victoria war der Name der Königin, nicht Viktoria. Ich wäre nicht damit einverstanden, wenn man meinen Namen übersetzt.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Wenn ich dran gedacht hätte, dann hätte ich aber wohl auch Neoviktorianisch geschrieben. Ich denke, als der Begriff geprägt wurde, schrieb man es so, und abgesehen davon, dass man Königin Viktoria nicht mehr fragen kann, wäre sie gewiss einverstanden, wenn man ihren Namen in Deutschland Deutsch schreibt. Wie schreibst Du eigentlich Kleopatra und Nofretete? :)

Comment: @userunknown: Du meinst sicher Königin Victoria? Man schreibt doch auch nicht König TSchortsch, oder Prinz Willjam?

Comment: @user: Und Nofretete oder Kleopatra haben keine eigene Schreibweise in unserer Schrift, also da kann man ja nicht anders (obwohl man in anderen Sprachen eher Nefertiti oder Nefertete schreibt). Aber man schreibt doch auch nicht Julius Zäsar, oder?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Natürlich haben Nofretete und Kleopatra eine eigene Schreibweise in unserer Schrift oder hälst Du das für Hyroglyphen? Bzgl. Viktoria: Der Begriff viktorianisch etablierte sich in einer anderen Zeit und dass nach Prinz Billy mal eine Epoche benannt wird, das wird man erst sehen müssen. Womöglich etabliert sich dann für diese ein Name, der sich von der Schreibung des Vornamens abkoppelt. Dass es heute wieder zu einer Germanisierung käme habe ich nicht behauptet.

Comment: @user: "Natürlich haben Nofretete und Kleopatra eine eigene Schreibweise in unserer Schrift". Haben sie das wirklich, oder gibt es da einfach viele verschiedene  Interpretationen?

Comment: Du kannst Kleopatra schreiben, das ist eine eigene Schreibweise in unserer Schrift, oder Cleopatra, das ist eine andere, eigene Schreibweise in unserer Schrift. In beiden Fällen ist es jedenfalls nicht die Originalschreibweise, von der ich vermute, dass es Hieroglyphen sind - aber ich nicht vom Fach.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Du meinst König Georg, oder? Und sagst du "William der Eroberer" statt "Wilhelm der Eroberer"? "Louis der Vierzehnte" oder "Ludwig der Vierzehnte"? "Johann Ohneland" oder "John Ohneland" (oder "John Lackland"?) "Kaiser Konstantin" oder "Kaiser Constantinus"? "König Ottokar" oder "König Otakar"? Im 19. Jahrhundert macht man das nicht mehr immer (Louis-Philippe, nicht Ludwig-Philipp), aber grundsätzlich spricht nichts gegen Königin Viktoria. (Man sagt ja auch Viktor Immanuel, nicht Vittorio Emmanuele).

Comment: @Sfg: Ja, sage ich: George, William, Louis, Constantinus usw.

Answer (score 4):

Die Silbe *neo* bedeutet auf Deutsch *neu*, wird aber seit wenigen Jahrzehnten nicht mehr übersetzt, hat also einen Status der dem eines Fremdwortes oder Lehnwortes entspricht.

Für das Adjektiv *victorian* wurde bereits in der Vergangenheit eingedeutscht. Seine deutsche Form ist *viktorianisch*.

Dann gibt es noch diesen Bindestrich. Dieser ist in der deutschen Version optional. Damit kann man das englische Adjektiv *neo-victorian* wir folgt ins Deutsche übersetzen:

> - neuviktorianisch
> - neu-viktorianisch
> - neoviktorianisch
> - neo-viktorianisch